# Manipulating and converting mixture ratios

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, ratio

I am unable to understand the following calculation for the total-fat to total-mixture ratio (adding the numerator and denominator values and taking the ratio of the two values). Also I am unable to understand what is going on in the last line, and how they have calculated the values as per the given requirements from the ratio. I am really unable to decipher this so I am requiring some help and guidance.

[image]

Comment: It's better to write everything out here, than to ask users to chase links offsite.

Comment: You have $1287$ ml of milk of each type. What they basically did was to calculate the amount of fat in each type of milk. Now when you mix all three types, you will get net fat amount equal to the sum of fat amount in each type of milk, and hence the numerator. Can you now think how they obtained the amount of non-fat contents in the mixture?

Comment: I  find it more intuitive to write it like this $$\frac{\frac{572}{1287}c+\frac{585}{1287}c+\frac{594}{1287}c}{c+c+c}$$ where c is the quantity of each type of milk. $c$ could be any arbitrary amount, but yields a highly simplified fraction when it is equal to 1287 ml.

Comment: @JohnJoy I still could not get the calculation. Can you please elaborate the steps slightly. How are we straightaway writing (c+c+c) in the denominator?

Comment: @ReluctantMetallurgist if $c$ is the amount of each type of milk in a preparation, then $c+c+c$ is the total amount of milk. The numerator is the total amount of fat in the preparation.

Comment: @JohnJoy I get you now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Related questions:

if you mix in equal quantity drinks with alcohol content $40\%$ and $44\%$, what is the alcohol percentage of the mixture?

if you mix in equal quantity drinks with alcohol content $40\%$, $44\%$  and $51\%$, what is the alcohol content of the mixture?

in a drink with alcohol content $40\%$, what is the ratio of alcohol to water?

If you can reply to the above questions, you will understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

We are given that the three milks have **fat:nonfat** ratios $$4:5,\quad 5:6\;\;\text {and }\; 6:7,\tag{*}$$ and asked to find the **fat:nonfat** ratio of a mixture containing *equal quantities* of the three milks.

- Let's convert the milks' **fat:nonfat** ratios to a form in which
  the milks' quantities (i.e., combined fat & nonfat contents) are
  easier to compare and standardise: the respective
  **fat:TotalContents** ratios are $$4:9,\quad 5:11\;\;\text {and }\; 6:13\tag1$$$$=572:1287,\quad 585:1287\;\;\text {and }\; 594:1287$$
  $(1287$ is the lowest common multiple of $9, 11, 13).$

  So, their **fat:nonfat** ratios are  $$572:715,\quad
  585:702\;\;\text {and }\; 594:693.$$ So, a $1:1:1$ mixture of the
  three milks has **fat:nonfat** ratio
  $$(572+585+594):(715+702+693)$$$$=1751:2110.\tag2$$

  Note that $(2)$ is just the weighted average
  $$\frac{715}{2110}\left(\frac{572}{715}\right)+\frac{702}{2110}\left(\frac{585}{702}\right)+\frac{693}{2110}\left(\frac{594}{693}\right)$$
  and alternatively derivable from the simple average of $(1):$
  $$\frac13\left(\frac49+\frac5{11}+\frac6{13}\right)\;:\;1-\frac13\left(\frac49+\frac5{11}+\frac6{13}\right).$$

Note that taking neither the simple nor weighted average of $(*)$ results in the correct answer, because *the three ratios' ratio units are not of the same size*. To throw this into relief, here's an explicit formulation of the given problem:

- Given that $$(4+5)x=(5+6)y=(6+7)z,$$ evaluate
  $$\frac{4x+5y+6z}{5x+6y+7z}.$$

To perform this evaluation, just express each of $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x,$ which will then get cancelled out to give the above numerical answer.